# Java ArrayList acting up

Tags: java, database, arraylist

I am running in to an odd issue. I have a database with 6 different "bids". I am trying to extract the bids with the following code:

```
public ArrayList<ProjectBid> getProjectBids(String projectID)
    {
        ArrayList<ProjectBid> result = new ArrayList<ProjectBid>();

        ProjectBid bid = new ProjectBid();

        try{

        st = con.createStatement();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM bids WHERE projectID=\""+projectID+"\"";
        System.out.println(query);
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);


        while (rs.next())
          {
            bid.setProjectID(projectID);
            bid.setBidID(rs.getString("bidID"));
            bid.setBidderEmail(rs.getString("bidder_email"));
            bid.setBidAmount(rs.getInt("bid_amount"));
            bid.setBidMessage(rs.getString("bid_message"));
            bid.setTimestamp(rs.getString("timestamp"));

            result.add(bid);
          }
          st.close();

        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println("Exception: "+ex);
        }

        return result;          
    }
```

For some reason my ArrayList result is giving me 6 identical "bid" objects instead of adding each of the "bids" from my database individually. The code runs through the ResultSet as expected and the correct values for each run is printed correctly if I add `"System.out.println(bid.getBidID);"` inside my while-loop. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should move `ProjectBid bid = new ProjectBid();` inside the while loop. With the current code you are updating the same `bid` variable which is defined outside the `while` loop hence it gets the last record's value after the loop completes.

Answer (score 3):

Add

```
ProjectBid bid = new ProjectBid();
```

in your `while` loop. As of now you are just overwriting the same `ProjectBid` object. So each reference in you `ArrayList` is pointing to the same object value of which you keep changing in your loop. So at the end you will have all elements in `ArrayList` with data same as last row retrieved from the database.

```
    while (rs.next())
      {
        ProjectBid bid = new ProjectBid();
        bid.setProjectID(projectID);
        bid.setBidID(rs.getString("bidID"));
        bid.setBidderEmail(rs.getString("bidder_email"));
        bid.setBidAmount(rs.getInt("bid_amount"));
        bid.setBidMessage(rs.getString("bid_message"));
        bid.setTimestamp(rs.getString("timestamp"));

        result.add(bid);
      }
```

Comment: Then I will create a new "bid" object for each row in my database. How will  that effect my memory usage if I have 1000 bids? Shouldn't overriding the same object work just as fine?

Comment: @user3586514:  No.  First, you're going to be overwriting existing data with the current approach (this answer is correct); second, the lifecycle of each new `ProjectBid` object lasts only until the end of the loop; each one will be eligible for garbage collection.

Comment: No it will not. All `add()` method does it add a reference to the object you pass. So as I said earlier at the end of loop all your array list references will point to same object. You need separate objects to save your distinct database row entries.

Comment: @user3586514 You could define a variable outside the loop but you have to reassign it with a `new` operator inside the loop.

Comment: @user3586514 No it shouldn't and you already noticed that it doesn't work. And yes it effect your memory... a little bit. Don't care about that.

Comment: @Makoto *"the lifecycle of each new ProjectBid object lasts only until the end of the loop; each one will be eligible for garbage collection."* So it doesn't matter that the ArrayList `result` still has a reference to these objects? Would be something new. I guess you meant the variables, not the referenced objects.

Comment: @Tom:  I hadn't noticed the `result` list at the end there.  It's what I get for reading things with smudged glasses, I suppose.  The elements wouldn't be eligible for garbage collection in that case, but 1,000 elements is *really small* in comparison with the sheer amount of elements one *could* bring back.

Comment: So you have a new reference for each new `ProjectBid ` instance. That will only take up stack space and only till the loop is in the context. Actual instances however will not be GCed unless all references to it are null including the ones in ArrayList.

Answer (score 1):

Since the reference to the bid is always the same thereby, it is overwriting the bid with the current value that in turn is changing all the bids in the result list giving you the last bid added.

Instantiate the bid object inside your loop and this should work fine.

```
while (rs.next())
  {
    ProjectBid bid = new ProjectBid();
    ...
    ...
    ...
    result.add(bid);
  }
```